# Create AWS AutoScalingGroup keeping existing ASG

Tags: terraform

I was expecting that a new ASG will always be created every time I update the userdata in my aws_launch_template. The only thing "terraform plan and apply" did is updated the aws_launch_template.example. It never created a new ASG in Amazon nor it created a new EC2 instance. What I'd like to see is a new ASG entry so that I can decide if I should terminate previous ASG or not. I changed the code from using name to name_prefix and hoping it will achieve what I want. It didn't.

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example" {
  name_prefix = "example-asg-${var.environment}-${random_id.example.hex}"
  launch_template {
    id = aws_launch_template.example.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }
  desired_capacity          = 1
  max_size                  = 3
  min_size                  = 1
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  vpc_zone_identifier       = ["subnet-000000"]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "example-instance"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to create a new ASG everytime you update the user data? the normal approach for this would be an instance refresh https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group#instance_refresh. An instance refresh will do a rolling deployment of your new config replacing your EC2 instances based on the instance refresh rules.

Comment: you can read more about this AWS feature here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/asg-instance-refresh.html

Comment: I'd like to mimic what the opensource deployment tool does to our setup. When  a developer makes changes to his git project, it goes to jenkins to build. Then spinnaker redeploys everything. I can see a new ASG is created every time they do a deployment.